# How to specify the model version label in a REST API request?

Tags: tensorflow-serving

As described in the documentation, using the `version_labels` field, you can specify a label to a model version in order to handle canary deployments.

https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/g3doc/serving_config.md#assigning-string-labels-to-model-versions-to-simplify-canary-and-rollback

For example, you can have model 43 labeled as `stable` and model 44 labeled as `canary`.

That feature sounds really neat, but I did not find in the doc how to adapt my POST request to specify the label I want to use.

Until now, I was using something of the sort:

```
curl -d '{"instances": <<my input data>>}' -X POST http://localhost:8501/v1/models/<<my model name>>:predict
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Please try with 
curl -d '{"instances": <<my input data>>}' -X POST http://localhost:8501/v1/models/<<my model name>>/labels/<vserion label>:predict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update:

Based on comments on [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/1413) GitHub Issue, @misterpeddy states that, as of August 14th 2019:

> Re: not being able to access the version using labels via HTTP - this is something that's not possible today (AFAIR) - only through the grpc interface can you declare labels :(

To the best of my knowledge, this feature is yet to be implemented.

#### Original Answer:

It looks like the current implementation of the HTTP API Handler expects the version to be numeric.

You can see the regular expression that attempts to parse the URL [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/e085cb37b4b5c62154aa063dcbb781b24d5b3fd4/tensorflow_serving/model_servers/http_rest_api_handler.cc#L57).

```cpp
prediction_api_regex_(
          R"((?i)/v1/models/([^/:]+)(?:/versions/(\d+))?:(classify|regress|predict))")
```

The `\d` defines an expectation for a numeric version indicator rather than a text label.

I've opened a corresponding TensorFlow Serving issue [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/1555).

Answer (score 0):

The REST API for TensorFlow Serving is defined here: https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/api_rest#url_4

For the predict method it would be:

```
http://host:port/v1/models/${MODEL_NAME}[/versions/${MODEL_VERSION}]:predict
```

where `${MODEL_VERSION}` would be `stable` or `canary`

Comment: Hi William, this is working for exact versions, like 1, 2, etc. but not for labels.

When I try to request my "symplemodel", I get `{ "error": "Malformed request: POST /v1/models/simple_model/versions/stable:predict" }`

But requesting `/v1/models/simple_model/versions/3:predict` is working.